# PIC Programming for variable to switch between 2 states

Tags: c, embedded, pic, keypad

New to programming. Using PIC18F4520 with a MM74C922N 4x4 matrix keypad connected to Port A bits 0 to 3. Basically this keypad has a 4 bit output(DCBA) that corresponds to what key was pressed based on the table below. What  I want to do is to have a variable switch between 2 states when the '1' key is pressed(DCBA = 0000). When '1' is pressed, variable = 1. When '1' is pressed again, variable = 2. When '1' is pressed yet again, variable = 1. So and and so forth... Any help is appreciated

Code:

`char keypressed[16] = { '1', '2', '3', 'F', '4', '5', '6', 'E', '7', '8', '9', 'D', 'A', '0', 'B', 'C' };`

```
if(key == keypressed[0])
... //Variable setting
```

[image: Table]

Comment: This is too broad to be answered really. Depending on how the keys are connected to the physical port pins, you probably can cook up some manner of look-up table. It isn't clear if this is a 4x4 keyboard matrix either, or something else.

Comment: It is a 4x4 matrix keypad. The DCBA out pins are connected to Port A bits 0 to 3. I already have the 'if keypressed = 1' statements. Just unsure on what to do after that to deal with the variable

Comment: You should probably provide a schematic and the source code you have so far. But that means this question is likely more suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead. Microcontroller programming is perfectly on-topic there.

Comment: @TomEsther Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @TomEsther If I understood correctly you just want to switch back and forth between value 1 and 2 for variable. That is, you want to assign variable a value of 1 if user presses 1 and if user again presses 1 you want to assign variable a value of 2.
Am I correct?

Comment: @GauravPathak Correct

Comment: Understood, I am just posting a sample code, cause I don't have a uC setup as you.

Comment: You need at least one port pin more, which signals when a key is pressed at all. Pin 12 tells you "data available".

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you want to switch back and forth between values for a particular variable.

In order to achieve this you can store those two values in an array and then use XOR operation to change the index of the array and assign the value to the variable as show in the sample/example code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int values[2] = {1,2};
    int var = values[0];
    int idx = 0;
    int userinp = 0;
    
    do {
        printf("Enter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &userinp);
        if(userinp == 1) {
            idx = idx ^ 1;
            printf("idx:: %d\n", idx);
            var = values[idx];
            printf("var: %d\n", var);
        }
            
    }while(userinp != EOF); 
}
```

Comment: Using this code, if the user pressed key 3 times, idx will be 3. var = values[2] which is invalid?

Comment: No @TomEsther, you are basically missing the operation of XOR. The initial value of `idx` is `0`, `int idx = 0`. It is being XORed with `1`, `idx = idx ^ 1`; so `1 ^ 0 = 1`, the `idx` will get updated with value `1` and in the next iteration it will be `1 ^ 1 = 0`. So, the variable `idx` will only have value either `0` or `1` at any instance.

Comment: You shouldn't use naive `int` on a PIC. Use `uint8_t` everywhere.

Comment: @GauravPathak Oh ok I get it, but what if I were to instead of a variable, use a singular port pin. So now it switches between HIGH('1') and LOW('1') states?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of switching between two values.  This method uses the following

```
x = a + b  - x
```

to switch the values of x between a and b.  So if you wish to switch between 0 and 5, 1 and 4 or 2 and 3 it would be

```
x = 5 - x
```

The big problem with this technique is that x must be initialized.  It can go wildly wrong if x is not initialized.  So to switch between 1 and 2, a + b = 3.  Using @GauravPathak's code, it would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var = 1;
    int userinp = 0;

    do {
        printf("Enter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &userinp);
        if(userinp == 1) {
            var = 3 - var;
            printf("var: %d\n", var);
        }    
    }while(userinp != EOF); 
}
```